# IOS: show a login screen

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I'm currently busy making an ios app and made the following interface with the storyboard:

[image]

I am a new with making apps for the iPhone and had the following question on my mind. I want to check when the app gets started if the user is logged in and if not, a login screen will popup and show. I'va read something about showing it modally however how can I do that programmatically? I have already created a LoginViewController

EDIT:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DashboardViewController : UINavigationController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet LoginViewController *LoginViewController;

@end
```

Its here at the Class of the first tab item.

This is the file structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/010hS.png

Answer (score 0):

To show a viewController modally you would do:

```
[self presentModalViewController:yourController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But how do I declare the LoginViewController? Need some help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You know, you should link your loginViewController to the view controller that'll call loginViewController.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet LoginViewController *loginViewController; // link to IB
```

then,

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.loginViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This creates the error  /Users/mattle/apps/timetable/timetable/timetable/DashboardViewController.h:13:40: Unknown type name 'LoginViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Comment: Do you have a class that named "LoginViewController'?

Comment: @seung Yes, so it's weird :S

Comment: Hey, a variable LoginViewController's name is must not be same with Class "LoginViewController". plz change a variable name LoginViewController to loginViewController  `LoginViewController *loginViewController;` like this

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing the class "LoginViewController". Below "#import " add "#import "LoginViewController.h":

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginViewController.h"
```

Then, where you want to show the LoginViewController:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.loginViewController animated:YES];
```

A suggestion, use "weak" for the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet LoginViewController *loginViewController;
```